# How to install windows xp in a system which is having ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems

I want to install Windows XP in a system which is having Ubuntu Linux. I don't want Ubuntu Linux, I want only Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your cd and boot as nothing was installed on your machine. The XP installer won't even notice ubuntu installation.

Comment: It depends on how your partitions are set up. If you have an NTFS partition already, it might offer to use that and Ubuntu would still be sitting in its own partition, unused. If you want to be sure, I'd say use Gparted Live (gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), delete all your current partitions (make sure you've backed up any data you want to keep) and then put in one big NTFS partition filling the whole drive (assuming that's what you want). The XP installer should detect the partition and allow you to install to it. Goodbye, Ubuntu!

Comment: The ubuntu partition will be shown as unpartitioned, if I recall correctly.